Expect Script TCL ending early
I have the following expect script which works for the most part. I have it connecting to a Cisco switch (eventually a couple hundred) and configuring syslog servers. It checks to make sure that buffering wasn't already configured and if it isn't, set it.
If "logging buffered" is set, the script works fine. However, if "no logging buffered" is present, the script dies early before saving the config.
    set timeout -1
    set ip [lindex $argv 0]
    set host [lindex $argv 1]
    set username "admin"
    set password "password"
    set prompt "#|%|>|\$ $"
    set timestamp [timestamp -format %Y-%m-%d_%H:%M]
    
    log_file ./$host.$timestamp.log
    
    spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$ip
    
    match_max 100000
    
    expect {
        "assword:" { send "$password\r" }
        "continue connecting (yes/no)?" {
        send "yes\r"
            expect {
            "assword:" { send "$password\r" }
            }
        }
    }
    expect "#"
    send -- "\r"
    expect "#"
    send -- "conf t\r"
    expect "#"
    send -- "logging on\r"
    expect "#"
    send -- "do show run | inc logging buffered\r"
    expect {
            "no logging buffered" {send "logging buffered 16384\r"; exp_continue}
            "#"  {send "\r"}
           }
    expect "#"
    send -- "logging host 1.2.3.4 transport tcp port 514\r"
    expect "#"
    send -- "logging host 1.2.3.5 transport tcp port 514\r"
    expect "#"
    send -- "logging trap notifications\r"
    expect "#"
    send -- "end\r"
    expect "#"
    send -- "wr mem\r"
    expect "#"
    send -- "exit\r"

With "no logging buffered" present
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@192.168.1.2
(admin@192.168.1.2) Password:

core-switch#
core-switch#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
core-switch(config)#logging on
core-switch(config)#do show run | inc logging buffered
no logging buffered
core-switch(config)#logging buffered 16384
core-switch(config)#
core-switch(config)#logging host 1.2.3.4 transport tcp port 514
core-switch(config)#logging host 1.2.3.5 transport tcp port 514
core-switch(config)#logging trap notifications
core-switch(config)#end
root@ubuntu:~/test#

With "logging buffered xyz" present
root@ubuntu:~/test# ./config-syslog-password.sh
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@192.168.1.2
(admin@192.168.1.2) Password:

core-switch#
core-switch#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
core-switch(config)#logging on
core-switch(config)#do show run | inc logging buffered
logging buffered 16384
core-switch(config)#
core-switch(config)#logging host 1.2.3.4 transport tcp port 514
core-switch(config)#logging host 1.2.3.5 transport tcp port 514
core-switch(config)#logging trap notifications
core-switch(config)#end
core-switch#wr mem
Building configuration...
[OK]
core-switch#root@ubuntu:~/test#

Now I know its something to do with the TCL but I can't figure out what. Any help will be appreciated.

I'm not convinced it's an Expect problem. Run the script with expect -d to enable verbose debugging, and let's see what it's doing under the hood.

Also, the code you posted does not match the output: the script calls logging on before conf t, but that's not what we see. Did you really post the code you're actually running?

you caught, me. I fixed the script putting logging after conf t but for got to update it here.

here is an expect -d. Looks to just skip over the wr mem going from end right to exit.
https://pastebin.com/raw/GJfnwQzx

I believe the problem is that you get out of step if you see no logging buffered, and that each expect "#" is actually matching the previous # to the one you hope it does.  There is one # that is output by the do show run ..., one from the logging buffered 16384 and one from the empty \r, but you only read 2 of them. Adding another expect "#" before the send "logging buffered 16384" should fix it.
